# In Quartz.net, how do I prevent a job running concurrently when using a single IJob?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.Net within a Windows Service to handle the scheduling of various jobs that I will be running. These jobs live inside of a database and each job is handled by a factory method inside of a separate class library.

I want to prevent the scheduler from running more than 1 of my jobs at a single time, however I can't use the `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute because I only have a single `IJob` in the scheduler - my factory method in a separate library handles the decision of what job to run.

Below is my single `IJob`:

```
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        int jobId = dataMap.GetInt("JobId");
        logger.InfoFormat("Job {0} has been triggered.", jobId);

        //Create a new Job Instance
        JobInstance jobInstance = new JobInstance()
        {
            CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExecutionState = ExecutionState.Running,
            CreateSource = "Agent Scheduler Service",
            Job = new Job() { Id = jobId }
        };

        middlewareRepository.CreateJobInstance(jobInstance);
        var job = jobFactory.GetJobImplementation(jobInstance);

        //execute the job
        job.Execute();
        logger.InfoFormat("Job {0} has been executed.", jobId);
    }
```

In this, there is a `jobId` which is my key for my job that I want to only allow a single instance to run at any given time.

This is how I load the jobs:

```
protected void LoadJobs()
{
    logger.Info("Loading jobs.");
    var jobs = middlewareRepository.GeActiveJobs();

    foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<JobDespatcher>()
            .WithIdentity(job.Description)
            .UsingJobData("JobId", job.Id)
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithCronSchedule(job.CronExpression)
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        logger.InfoFormat("Job with id {0} ({1}) has been scheduled.", job.Id, job.Description);
    }
}
```

Is there a way within Quartz.net to prevent the same job from running twice based on a key or a piece of data?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to do locks in .net? If not it sounds like you want to look into that. The lock keyword (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) allows the enclosed bit of code to be entered by one thing at a time (and will wait until everybody else is out if needed). Monitor.TryEnter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter(v=vs.110).aspx) will allow you to skip executing the code if somebody else is already running it...

Comment: you may try to set the number of threads in the quartz.net threadpool equal to 1. In the web.config file add next  under quartz section:
`<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="20" />`

Comment: @Set that will prevent all jobs from running concurrently. I want as many IJobs to run as possible however within an IJob I, I have a "Job Group" and only want one type of job from the job group to run at any one time

Comment: by the way, what stops you to apply `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` on your single `IJob` instance? I mean that one, that has above `Execute` method. As you execute `created` job synchronously, it is enough for you to ensure, that only one `Execute` method is running at a time.

Comment: @Set you are absolutely right. I read the docs and realize that it disallows based on the JobKey and not based on the class itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute on your single IJob instance. I mean that one, that has above `Execute` method. As you execute created job synchronously, it is enough for you to ensure, that only one `Execute method is running at a time.

Comment: But two different jobs will run at the same time

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Cheers!